# Как выделить массивы из одного в другой массив?

Tags: php

Есть например у меня массив типа :

```
array = [
  0 = [
     Propery = '1';
  ]
  1 = [
     Propery = '2';
  ]
  2 = [
     Propery = '1';
  ]
  3 = [
     Propery = '3';
  ]
  4 = [
     Propery = '2';
  ]
  5 = [
     Propery = '1';
  ]
]
```

На выходе хочу получить массив типа

```
array = [
 0 = [
  0 = [
     Propery = '1';
  ]
  2 = [
     Propery = '1';
  ]
  5 = [
     Propery = '1';
  ]
 ]
 1 = [
  1 = [
     Propery = '2';
  ]
  4 = [
     Propery = '2';
  ]
 ]
  3 = [
    3 = [
     Propery = '3';
  ]
 ]
]
```

То-есть чтобы получить все массивы, отсортированные по группам за кое-каким показателем. Пробовал сам писать, но выходил слишко громоздкой и плохой код.
Может есть какое-то универсальное решение с помощью станд. функций php?

Comment: А можно воспроизводимые массивы? В формате исходного кода php, а не `var_dump` (Или что это у вас за формат?)

Comment: @vp_arth это я для примера ввел, что типо есть массивы, в которых параметр, и мне нужно их сгруппировать по нему

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не совсем понятно в чем заключается сложность такого преобразования. Если по факту преобразование сложнее, чем приведенный пример, то лучше таки дополнить вопрос.

Для исходных данных вида:

```
$data = [
    [ 'property' => 1 ],
    [ 'property' => 2 ],
    [ 'property' => 1 ],
    [ 'property' => 3 ],
    [ 'property' => 2 ],
    [ 'property' => 1 ],
];
```

требуемый результат будет получен с помощью следующего цикла:

```
$result = [];
foreach($data as $k => $v){
    $result[$v['property']][$k] = $v;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach($array as $k => $val):
    switch (creteria_definition):
        case 'creteria_1':
            $new_array[0][$k] = $v;
            dreak; 
        case 'creteria_2':
            $new_array[1][$k] = $v;
            dreak;
        case 'creteria_3':
            $new_array[2][$k] = $v;
            dreak;
    ebdswitch;
endforeach;
```

Comment: к сожалению у меня тут вариант - пример. Так-то у меня может быть их штук 30 разных значений параметров. И каждый записывать через свитч не очень логично.

Comment: Вряд ли Вы найдёте более упрощённую функцию, где можно будет 30 критериев сравнивать со значением каждого элемента массива и сортировать. Но, если найдёте, дайте знать, я уже и сам призадумался.